# Jersey bean validation is not working in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, bean-validation, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy an application to weblogic and we are using jersey as a jsr 303 bean validation provider

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have disabled the default bean validation implementation in weblogic inside weblogic.xml -->

```
<prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.bootstrap.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.constraints.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.groups.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.metadata.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

now I'm getting this error, it's not seeing jersey bean validation at all :

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$DefaultConfigurationProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationBinder$DefaultConfigurationProvider.provide(ValidationBinder.java:110)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:153)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

**BTW the application is running fine in tomcat. any idea ?**

**EDIT**
I found a solution, I have to add all the dependencies not only javax.validation, jersey uses hibernate validator underthehood for bean validation and hibernate validator is using jboss for logging, so it worked with me when I added the following

```
<package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
<package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</package-name>
<package-name>org.jboss.logging.*</package-name>
```

Comment: WebLogic 12c supports JSR 303 natively (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm#NOTES258) while Jersey Bean Validation has a dependency on Hibernate provider. This may cause conflicts which you may try to resolve using weblogic.xml deployment descriptor.

Comment: Yes bro, it works.Thanks

Comment: @Sameh Plz, comment your solution.

Comment: @Matheus..Done
I've updated the question with the solution.